# Big Lists in Umbraco 7

Tags: list, umbraco, store

We are migrating our site from SharePoint to Umbraco 7, what is the best way to store & manage lists in Umbraco? in the current site in SharePoint We have a lot of lists.

NestedItems is not a very good solution because there is no option to search in or sort.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For each type of list you have, create a node that's configured to have a list view, then add each list item as a subnode to the parent node.

That way you get a good solution performance-wise, and you'll be able to search through the subnodes.

(Screenshot is from Umbraco 8, so UI to enable List View may be a little different from Umbraco 7, but the concept is the same)

[image: Screenshot: Enable list view in Umbraco document type]

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options, depending on what you need to achieve.
If you want to use the default Umbraco index for your content, you can create a doctype and enable list view on it, then any children of that node will be in a searchable/orderable list.

If you want to store the data in a custom database table, there is a package called Fluidity for Umbraco 7 which allows you to easily integrate this into the backoffice.
https://our.umbraco.com/packages/backoffice-extensions/fluidity/